# "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime" on a query that does not even have DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have downgraded my MySQL version to version 5.5 and I just came across this error. This is the query that I am trying to run with my program.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM CampaignParameters WHERE CampaignId=225
LIMIT 1;
COMMIT;
```

and I get the error:

```
Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
```

As you see, I don't even have a `DateTime` in my query.

The query works when I run it directly in MySQL but it generates the above error when I execute from inside my c# program.

Apparently, the solution is to add `Convert Zero Datetime=True`. But is there a way to set this value in our MySQL instead of adding a value to connection string?

**Update:**

Campaign Parameters Table
[image]

Code:

```
public string GetCampaignParameters(long campaignId)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sql = string.Format(@"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
                                    SELECT * FROM CampaignParameters WHERE CampaignId={0}
                                    LIMIT 1;
                                    COMMIT;", campaignId);
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
        }
        if (ds == null || ds.Tables == null || ds.Tables[0].Rows == null || ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            return "empty";
        else return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Params"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `CampaignParameters` columns and the C# code?

Comment: @segarci yes, I added both. My table actually had date columns but they were not used in the query. Mind that, the exact same function was working before I downgraded my MySQL version.